# Computer Vision : Pattern Matching using Gaussian Pyramids

Tags: pattern-matching, computer-vision

I am planning to implement a pattern matching algorithm using correlation as a matching metric.

I know that the template I am going to use will, if present, have different sizes in the target images. The interval of sizes might be something like : x 0.5 , x 0.75 , x 1.0 , x 1.25 , x 1.5 , x 2.0 of the original template size.

To speed up the search it is suggested in various articles to build a gaussian pyramid of both the template and the target search image.

However I am not able to relate in any meaningful way the number of pyramid octaves and levels to create (for model and for target) , the object scales as described above, and the gaussian filter sigmas (used when creating the pyramid) !

Could someone shed any light on this ?

For example, 1 octave of the pyramid reduces the resolution of the image by 2 : is this the same as saying that the image has been scaled by 0.5 ?

What about a pyramid octave of -1 (which should make the image bigger x 2.0) : should any filtering be applied before upsampling ?

Can a gaussian filter sigma for the scale space pyramid be deduced given a desired image scale, that is : if I know the template image can appear bigger or smaller in the target image, lets say x 1.25 or x 0.75 can I deduce from this the sigma to use for the gaussian smoothing kernel.

Can object scales (e.g. x 1.25) which fall in-between pyramid octaves be represented by pyramid levels ?

Thanks to anyone who could provide some insight/references,
Todor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you asking is something that is done by SIFT algorithm.

They used the following approach:
      starting sigma 1.2   (EXPERIMENTAL)
      step factor sqrt(2)  (EXPERIMENTAL)

Why they use octaves... performance!
      if they continued to grow sigma they would end in problem not beeing able to convolve an image in  real-time (well decent time), that is why they split the processing into octaves.

When they populate each octave (when they double the scale) they half the image size and convolve the resized image again.

Another paper measures the quality of parameters: sigma, scales per octave, number of octaves:
http://www.bmva.org/bmvc/2010/workshop/paper5/paper5.pdf

In short:
    build the Gaussian pyramid of the input image and a template with factor scale of 2 and blur each level with some small sigma.

```
Matching:
   match at the highest level (smallest images), then match the already matched object in lower level (in some area) just to improve precision.

 I do not think you need octaves since you are not going to convolve images with large sigmas (needed for blob detection like in SIFT)
```